# SQL CASE Statement (keeping the CASE statement within the WHERE clause)

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, case, where-clause, sql

I have a table named:

```
Ext_Meeting_Status
```

This has fields

1. Ext_Meeting_Status_ID
2. TEXT

The values are:

```
EXT_Meeting_Status_ID   Text
1   Draft
2   Published
3   Cancelled
4   Closed
```

How do i return the "Text" field of "Published" if date is today, else return "Close".

I tried using:

```
select * from Ext_Meeting_Status
where 
GETDATE() = CASE
    WHEN ( GETDATE() = '2010-12-13 10:02:31.560'  )
    THEN ( Ext_Meeting_Status_ID=2)
    ELSE ( Ext_Meeting_Status_ID=4)
    END
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select * from Ext_Meeting_Status 
   where   Ext_Meeting_Status_ID = 
    CASE WHEN (GETDATE() = '2010-12-13 10:02:31.560')  
    THEN (2)     
    ELSE (4)
 END
```

I believe this should work..

One more note : Comparing current date to the exact millisecond level might not work as the query may not get executed at that time...

You may try something like this.

```
Select getdate(), * from #Temp
  Where ID = Case when getdate() between '2010-12-13 05:21:08.240' and '2010-12-13 05:22:08.240'
                Then 1
                Else 2
             End
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible. You may want to try to put it all into a sub-select and use the CASE there.